# Need help finding an unbiased estimator

Tags: variance, exponential-distribution, unbiased-estimator, extreme-value

Suppose that the pdf for $T$ is exponentially distributed
$$f(x; θ) = \frac{1}
{θ}
e
^{−x/θ}
, 0 ≤ x < ∞$$.
Suppose we test n components and record the failure times $T_1, . . . , T_n$.

(a) Show that $\hatθ = \overline{T} = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} T_i$
is an unbiased estimator of $θ$.

(b) What is the variance of $\hatθ$?

(c) It can be shown that $Z = \min(T_1, . . . , T_n)$ also has an exponential distribution
with parameter $θ/n$. That is
$$g(z; θ) = \frac{1}
{θ/n}e^
{−z/(θ/n)}$$
(Do not show this). Use this to find
another unbiased estimator $\tilde{θ}$ of $θ$ and determine its variance.

Parts (a) and (b) are quite straightforward. But I'm having trouble with part (c). I know how to show something is an unbiased estimator but I'm unsure how to find an unbiased estimator. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and (if needed) modify your question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

1. What's $E(Z)$?
2. What's $E(aZ)$ for some constant $a$?
3. Choose a value of $a$ such that $E(aZ)=\theta$